# Move window from second screen to the main when the second screen is not visible

Tags: windows

I use a VPN and Windows remote desktop to log onto my Windows XP work computer from my Win Vista 64 home computer.

The only problem is that I sometimes forget to move all my important windows over to the main screen when I leave work. Does anyone know a way I can move the windows over to the main window without being able to see them?

So far the only way I know how to do this is by closing them and reopening, which is not an option for tests that has been running for multiple hours.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Right click on window in taskbar, choose Move and use arrow keys to move the window.

Optionally you can press Alt + Space when window is in focus to bring up the same menu with Move.

Window can't be maximized in order to move but you can Restore it using same menu.

Comment: awesome thanks! could not find that with google

Comment: I had to tell someone how to do this just recently, and ended up with the same solution.

Comment: One trick I've used to make this process a bit faster is to choose Move, press an arrow key to move the window a little, then use the mouse cursor.  The window follows the cursor back to your screen.

Comment: This is what I needed. Be aware that on my windows 7 machine I need to hold the shift button to get the move option in the menu.

Answer (score 18):

On Windows 7, start Task Manager, chooses "Applications" tab, select task, right-click with mouse, and do:
1. minimize.
2. maximize.

In my case, it brought widows that had been opening onto the second desktop, that I have disconected, onto the main desktop.

Comment: The minimize/maximize trick worked for me on XP too, just right clicking the item on the task bar at the bottom.  I've always used the method described in the accepted answer, but this is much easier!

Comment: This also works from Process Explorer in Windows 7.  Find the process in the list, right click on it and choose Window -> Minimize, then rick click again and choose Window -> Maximize.

Comment: This worked for me when the task bar would not.

Comment: Thanks. However it's actually the task manager which is on my second monitor which I need to move.

Comment: perfect solution for remote desktop to Win 7 from Mac